# iCloud running out of space, but it's not

Tags: icloud

I keep getting messages from iCloud saying my drive is out of room. It is not, it is about half full:

[image]

Any ideas here?

Comment: iCloud is more than the drive. If you go to AppleID/iCloud on macOS or iOS you should see the full breakdown of storage used in iCloud.

Comment: Indeed, it's Messages. Comments on maintaining this? Is there a "last 100 messages in a thread" setting?

Comment: You can limit the history in Settings/Preferences. Or delete large videos manually.

Comment: @nohillside - I'm not seeing this option in prefs. If I click Manage and then Messages, the only option I have is "Turn Off and Delete...". Am I missing another option? OH WAIT - on the iPhone :-)

Answer (score -1):

Open System Preferences and inspect your iCloud Storage there. What you are looking at in Finder is only the size of your iCloud Drive files.

After opening System Preferences, select "Apple ID" in the top row, or "iCloud" in the bottom row if you are running an older version of macOS. On this screen, you will see a meter indicating your storage usage. Hover over different segments to see information about them, and click "Manage" to see more detail.

[image: A screenshot showing the iCloud Storage meter]